# How to push specific fields of an objectlist in an array

Tags: angularjs

My question is to retain only specific field values from an object array , in my case here it is FirstName,LastName,PhoneNumber,Department,EmailId. A single object in object array $scope.devices has many fields but i want to retain only the above mentioned filed values for all the objects.

```
 // Angularjs part ,devices is the objecctlist    
    var deviceArray = []; 
           for(var entry in  $scope.devices)  {
           deviceArray.push({FirstName: entry.FirstName,
                             LastName:  entry.LastName,
                             PhoneNumber: entry.PhoneNumber,
                             EmailId : entry.EmailId,
                             Department : entry.Department,
                             });`
           };
           $log.debug('deviceArray :', deviceArray) //deviceArray : []
```

Comment: i don't know if you made mistake when you copied your code, but at the line 8 remove the ( , ) after department. And at line 9 remove this character ( ` )

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var deviceArray = [], fields = "FirstName,LastName,PhoneNumber,Department,EmailId";

angular.forEach($scope.devices, function(item){
    var temp = {};
    angular.forEach(fields.split(/[, ]+/), function(key){
        temp[key] = item[key]
    });
    deviceArray.push(temp)
});

console.log(deviceArray)
```

Comment: in the solution given by you i am getting an empty array..when I am trying to print its value.. deviceArray : Array[0] this is the output i am getting from $log.debug('deviceArray :', deviceArray) //deviceArray : []

Comment: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object] I am getting this as an output , all of them as strings

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with angular, it's better to use angular [forEach](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach)

You can do this in following way using angular forEach

```
var deviceArray = [];

angular.forEach($scope.devices,function(entry,key){     

      deviceArray.push({    
                            FirstName: entry.FirstName,
                            LastName:  entry.LastName,
                            PhoneNumber: entry.PhoneNumber,
                            EmailId : entry.EmailId,
                            Department : entry.Department,
                      }); 

    })
```

**for in**  will give index number and not an Object.Using that index you have to access actual object in that array.

```
var deviceArray = [];
          for(var entry in  $scope.devices){
            deviceArray.push({
                              FirstName: $scope.devices[entry].FirstName,
                              LastName:  $scope.devices[entry].LastName,
                              PhoneNumber: $scope.devices[entry].PhoneNumber,
                              EmailId : $scope.devices[entry].EmailId,
                              Department : $scope.devices[entry].Department,
                            });
          }
```

Comment: in either the solution given by you i am getting an empty array..when I am trying to print its value..  deviceArray : Array[0] this is the output i am getting from      $log.debug('deviceArray :', deviceArray) //deviceArray : []

Comment: @AvishekParihary check this http://plnkr.co/edit/wZPQxhYLUcFw9N0vxuiT?p=preview   Also Please check your "$scope.devices" data.Please share the updated script

Comment: $$hashKey: "object:47"CreateDate: "2015-05-26T07:14:45Z"CreateSource: ""CreateUserId: 4Department: "sales"DeviceId: "device1"EmailId: "user1@sample.com"FirstName: "user1"GenDeviceId: "d31e49b6-54cd-4887-6a5c-21ce15cb03ad"GroupId: ""GroupName: ""GroupRows: Array[2]Id: 1LastName: "userLast1"PhoneNumber: 988927898SelectExistGroup: false
This is the data structure for a single object.

Comment: The structure for scope.devices is [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]

Comment: so i need a similar array of objects with only the particular fields as mentioned above

Comment: Please refer this updated script http://plnkr.co/edit/wZPQxhYLUcFw9N0vxuiT?p=preview .

Comment: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object] I am getting this as an output , all of them as strings

Comment: @AvishekParihary Is it possible share jsfiddle or plunker.? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In form `for (var entry in $scope.devices)` you are looping over keys of the array as object, so `entry` is 0, 1, etc.

You should use `for (var i = 0; i < ...)` loop for arrays:

```
 var deviceArray = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < $scope.devices.length; i++) {
     var entry = $scope.devices[i];
     deviceArray.push({
         FirstName: entry.FirstName,
         LastName: entry.LastName,
         PhoneNumber: entry.PhoneNumber,
         EmailId: entry.EmailId,
         Department: entry.Department,
     });
 };
```

However in this case it's optimal to use [Array.prototype.map:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
var deviceArray = $scope.devices.map(function(entry) {
    return {
         FirstName: entry.FirstName,
         LastName: entry.LastName,
         PhoneNumber: entry.PhoneNumber,
         EmailId: entry.EmailId,
         Department: entry.Department,
     };
});
```

Comment: for ur first case i get an error..Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: What is the `console.log($scope.devices)`?

Comment: [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]        

This is the output when i do a $log.debug($scope.devices) and the structure of a single object is like

Comment: $$hashKey: "object:47"CreateDate: "2015-05-26T07:14:45Z"CreateSource: ""CreateUserId: 4Department: "sales"DeviceId: "device1"EmailId: "user1@sample.com"FirstName: "user1"GenDeviceId: "d31e49b6-54cd-4887-6a5c-21ce15cb03ad"GroupId: ""GroupName: ""GroupRows: Array[2]Id: 1LastName: "userLast1"PhoneNumber: 988927898SelectExistGroup: false this is the structure of a single object

Comment: With this structure `$scope.devices.length` should be fine. I guess your code is different in some way.